# what does "on the go" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Before starting Hike, he founded a start-up that launched an iPhone app that allowed users to buy movie tickets on the go.

source: http://www.cnbc.com/2016/05/31/bharti-airtel-chairman-sunil-mittals-son-kavin-betting-big-on-mobile-app-hike.html

Answer (score 1):

"On the go" is an idiomatic expression and it describes someone who always seems to be in motion, actively traveling, buisy:

> A: John is always on the go. How does he find time to write fiction?
>
> B: Maybe he doesn't sleep.

It also means something to have started:

> The serial is now on the go.